# change columns with while loop

Tags: r, loops, while-loop

In the iris dataset, I want to replace the names setosa virginica and versicolor with a letter, then convert it to an A for example setosa with a while loop and put another letter A next to it.

so setosa = AA

virginica = BB

versicolor = CC

The code I tried only adds to the numbers, I need to do it to the letters

```
data(iris) 
head(iris) 
Burak <- iris

running_index <- 1

  while(is.numeric(iris[ , running_index])) { 
    iris[ ,running_index] <- iris[ ,running_index] + 50 
    running_index <- running_index + 1
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the simple below code without using `loop`!

```
data("iris")
iris$Species<-c(rep("AA", 50), rep("BB",50),
                rep ("CC", 50))
```

```
head(iris)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2      AA
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2      AA
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2      AA
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2      AA
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2      AA
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4      AA

tail(iris)
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5      CC
146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3      CC
147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9      CC
148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0      CC
149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3      CC
150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8      CC
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you’re trying to do? I really don’t follow the logic of your `while` loop or how it relates to your stated goal.

```
new_labels <- c(setosa = "AA", virginica = "BB", versicolor = "CC")

iris$Species <- new_labels[iris$Species]

iris[c(1, 61, 121), ]
```

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2      AA
61           5.0         2.0          3.5         1.0      BB
121          6.9         3.2          5.7         2.3      CC
```

Comment: I'm trying to replace them with while loop.
as in the sample code

Comment: That doesn’t really make sense, and even if it did would be a very inefficient way of doing it; in R, most operations are vectorized, meaning you should transform vectors / columns “all at once” in one operation rather than using a loop.

Comment: I try to learn R studio and sorry for my english.I have difficulty expressing myself. So, is there a way to loop the letters with the while command?

Comment: I’m sorry but I really just don’t understand. Could you edit your original question to provide more explanation of what you want, including an example of your desired output? Also look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/17303805) to learn more about asking an effective R question.